# Incorrect equation numbering

Tags: equations, cross-referencing

I'm having an issue with the numbering of my equations when report writing using subsections. Whenever I label the equations and refernce them, I would like to just get the number of the equation, however it appears that for equations within the same subsection I get the same equation number when I reference them. Can anyone help? I'm sure it's probably something silly.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}


\begin{document}

\section{Section 1}



\subsection{SubSection 1}

Random equation shown below:

\begin{equation}
v = \frac{d}{t}
\end{equation}
\label{eq:1}

This is Equation \ref{eq:1}. Another equation is:


\begin{equation}
E = mc^2
\end{equation}
\label{eq:2}

This is Equation \ref{eq:2}.

\subsection{Subsection 2}

This is another random equation:

\begin{equation}
F = ma
\end{equation}
\label{eq:3}

This is Equation \ref{eq:3}.
\end{document}
```

[image]

This is what the code attached produces for me. The same equation number however two different equations have been referenced.

Comment: `label` must be in `equation` environment like `\begin{equation}\label{eq:2}
E = mc^2
\end{equation}`

Comment: Yeah that's worked, knew I was being an idiot. Thanks.

Comment: Your welcome. It's just a lack of attention. :-)

Comment: @Aidan Sorry for my comment. Nobody is an idiot and also you.